# Http handler in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

Now i have asp mvc 5 .net framework  project and handlers (ashx files with custom logic) to process customer needs (i.e. pricelists in custom format).

I intend to move to asp core, and the question : **is there an equivalent to handler?**
Articles on internet suggest to put logic to middleware, but this is inconvenient way in my case.

Comment: I have a couple of points that will hopefully be helpful.  First, there's nothing 'wrong' with keeping your application in ASP.NET MVC, it's not going away.  The second point is, if you really need to move to ASP.NET Core, you should be using middleware in place of handlers, because the request life cycle is completely different.  Instead of hooking into the pipeline, middleware becomes part of the pipeline.  It removes a lot of the 'magic' and issues of "where is the right place, in the lifecycle, to hook this bit into?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you explain what you need that a middleware cannot provide for you?

Middleware are built in a way so that you can completely migrate from old Http Handlers/Modules to them.

[Migrating to Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: I don't want to change assembly if i need to add new handler. In mvc 5, if i need to add handler i merely add new file and put logic to it only

Comment: @LapenkovVladimir So you mean you want to put your **middleware** in another **assembly** and use it in your application?

Comment: Yo 're right cause middlewares suit better and lightweight here

Answer (score 1):

Razor pages with it's own logic and model best way to substitute custom handlers in my case

Answer (score 0):

You could use Middleware or Interceptor for tracking any incoming request.
The most important difference between them is that, you could use interceptor per any action too - for this you should use dependency injection.